# The developers of this app have not set up this app properly Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before anybody marks this as duplicate:

I have read almost all similar topics here without any solution for my particular case. I have an app which has passed "App details" review, has all the forms filled in (including contact email) and is **published** with full green circle in dashboard besides app name.

[image]

And yet I receive the same "The developers of this app have not set up this app properly.." message when trying to access the app:

[image]

Could it be that after publishing the app you have to wait for additional 24 hours before it *really* becomes public?

App ID: 387142881474933

Comment: Can you share your App ID, please?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you used an other app ID before? The authentication dialog that you are trying to open directs to App ID `639843166115642` (which is currently non-existing). Can you check your implementation and replace any occurrence of `639843166115642` with `387142881474933`?

Comment: Yep, that was it. I have tested the application before and created a new one for publishing but forgot to update the app ID in the authentication dialog within the html of the page